# conditional visibility of filters in tableau dashboard

Tags: tableau-desktop

I want to hide filter B and C when option 1 is selected and display filter A. Similarly, hide filters A and C when option 2 is selected and show filter B. Finally, hide filters A and B when option 3 is selected and show filter C.

Note that the option selection is a parameter with a list of values as strings, from which I created a calculation field.

This calculation field is added in the filters and displayed on the right side. In the filter edit, I included a custom value list for the selection to be displayed.

I implemented this for three charts, each with its filter (A, B, and C). In the dashboard, I placed the three charts inside a container along with the respective filters and the parameter selection filter.

i tried to hide on of the three filters each time

[image]

Comment: This feature is currently not supported by the software

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a work around solution.

Comment: You can do this today, or at least something very close) with Tableau's feature dynamic zone visibility feature https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/dynamic_zone_visibility.htm  You may need to create a parameter and boolean calculated fields to specify which filters are visible in which state - and use a parameter control or parameter action to switch states.

Comment: P.S. If you first top level filter only allows a single choice, then you can replace it with a parameter and a calculated field, which will simplify the effort of determining whether to show the other filters.

Comment: @Debayan the feature is supported - see my comment above

Comment: P.P.S. Rereading your post more carefully, I see that your "Option" field is already a parameter. So you are most of the way there already. Just make a boolean calculated field for each filter denoting whether it should be shown given the selected option, and use dynamic zone visibility to control when each filter is shown. You'll have to make sure a "hidden" filter still doesnt impact your results, so may need to use a calculated field for the filter and parameters or sets for the controls, nonetheless.